# Failed to deploy a war file in jboss 7.0

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, web-deployment

I have deploy a war file mavenproject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war in jboss directory JBOSS-BASE-DIR\standalone\deployments

I use maven for building the war file

And i start the server by clicking standalone.bat in JBOSS-BASE-DIR/bin/standalone.bat

But I am getting following error.

## #

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not index class org/hibernate/SQLQuery.cla
ss in archive '"/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/conten
t/mavenproject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar"'

## #

I have copy the war file in 
   "C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments" directory 
but they are trying to index org/hibernate/SQLQuery.class in 
/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/mavenproject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar

Can anybody could explain me why this happens

Comment: Try this with Jboss7.1.1 final. I think there was some issue in earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

content folder is the internal JBoss folder. Unrelated to that, on every deployment, it is using Jandex tool to index your deployment. For some reason, it seems to be stumbling on Hibernate SQLQuery class. It would seem that either hibernate binary .jar is broken or jandex tool used internally by JBoss has a bug.

Hibernate 4 is provided by JBoss out of the box, so you can get around this by using JBoss-provided module and setting your hibernate dependency to provided scope in maven.

Comment: It is not only for the case of hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar.I couldn't deploy any war file which has jar files in lib folder.Jbose will try to process jar files in the path "/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/application.war/WEB-INF/lib"  and the deployment will fail

Comment: @MidhunRavikumar of course it needs to process those files to get the deployment going, but failing deployment on that is strange. You could try with either a) newer version of JBoss or b) describe the contents of your war file, in case it has some of the .xmls that trigger extra processing